# Recurrence and Time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

I am having problem solving this recurrence. Can anyone help me with this please:

$$ T(n) = 2(T(\sqrt n))^2 , T(1) = 4. $$

Comment: I think the details are missing. $T(n) = 2(T(\sqrt n))^2$ does not hold for $n = 1$. ??

Answer (score 2):

Let $S(m) = \log_2 (2T(2^m))$. Then $S(m)$ satisfies the recurrence
$$
S(m) = 2S(m-1), \quad S(0) = 3.
$$
You can work it out from here.

Comment: Thank you. Can you pleas show you you just came up with $S(m) = 2S(m-1)$?

Comment: It's a calculation.

Comment: Thank you. So, we derive such equations based on linear recurrence formula or this is just change of variable technique please? Can you please give me a reference how to derive such equations?

Comment: It's a combination of a change of variables (twice – both input and output) and of slightly changing the recurrence (multiply the original recurrence by 2 on both sides to get a nicer expression).

Answer (score 1):

Solving by **Substitution**

Given,
$T(n)=2(T(\sqrt n))^2$

$T(n)=2(T(n^{1/2}))^2$

$T(n)=2(2(T(n^{1/4}))^2)^2$

$T(n)=2(2(2(T(n^{1/8}))^2)^2)^2$

$T(n)=2.2^2.2^4(T(n^{1/8}))^8$

$T(n)=2^{1+2+2^{2}}(T(n^{1/2^3}))^{2^3}$

Using Summation Formula for Geometric Progression
$T(n)=2^{(2^3-1)}(T(n^{1/2^3}))^{2^3}$

Therefore, for **k iterations**

### $T(n)=2^{(2^k-1)}(T(n^{1/2^k}))^{2^k}$

Now, **Assuming** that instead of $T(1)=4$, it is given that $T(2)=4$
(Since, $n^{1/2^k}=1$ will be possible when $n=1$ or $\frac{1}{2^k}=0$, which seems invalid as per algorithm)

Therefore, put $n^{1/2^k}=2$

$\frac{1}{2^k}{log_2n}=1$

${2^k}={log_2n}$

Thus,

### $T(n)=2^{({log_2n}-1)}(T(2))^{log_2n}$

$T(n)=2^{({log_2n}-1)}(4)^{log_2n}$
$T(n)=2^{({log_2n}-1)}(2)^{2log_2n}$
$T(n)=2^{({log_2n}-1)}2^{log_2{n^2}}$

### $T(n)=\frac{2^{({log_2n})}2^{log_2{n^2}}}{2}$

$T(n)=\frac{n^3}{2}$

### Thus, $T(n)$ is $O(n^3)$

Comment: Thank you. But it's not given that $T(2) = 4$, can you please explain that a little more?

Comment: @Avra If we assume that $T(1)=4$, we have to put $n^{1/2^k}=1$. Take logarithm (of any base) on both sides. It will make ${1/2^k}=0$ which is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. So you just used that invalidity to step upward and try $T(2)=4$ please?

Comment: @Avra, Yes it was pure assumption to solve further.